# How to Tag photo in facebook with certain position

Tags: facebook

this is my app image...this uploads friends photo but,.,,tag is not inrandom  position..please help me to tag friends image correctly
http://shapper.co.tv/1/hiii.jpg

Comment: You can refer this link. It will be helpful for you.[Simple image tagging page like facebook image tag][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833253/simple-image-tagging-page-like-facebook-image-tag/23129551#23129551

Answer (score -1):

Once you have the photo's Graph ID, you can tag your friends by passing the co-ordinate, like the following Graph API call with JS-SDK

```
if (accessToken) {
var data = {
    "access_token": accessToken,
    to:userId,
    x:x,
    y:y
}
FB.api("/" + photoId+"/tags/"+userId , 'post', data, function(response) {
    //here is the response
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have this..please help me with this $data []  = array(
                     'tag_uid' => $id,  
                     'x' => $m,
                     'y' => $n
                  );

Comment: Are you using PHP SDK or the JS-SDK? In your code above it looks like you are using the PHP SDK. You can use the following code if I am right
$fb->api("/{$photoId}/tags/{$userId}", "post", $data);

hope it will work.